# Text Box fill db values dynamically, based on dropdown selection in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have used two fields in my database, one field is the category and another field is mobile. I am already Displaying and fetch category values in drop down. I want to select those category value from dropdown then I want to show its mobile number in textbox field. I am working on this but not succeeded. please help me.

Dropdown box and textbox code:-

```
<?php
include('session.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user_content`";
$result1 = mysqli_query($db, $query);
 <select name="cat" id="cat"  style="width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #fff;"  required>
    <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>

            <option value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>"><?php echo $row1[4];?></option>

            <?php endwhile;?>
</select>
<input placeholder="Phone Number" name="phoneNumber" id="pnum"  type="text">
```

Jquery and Ajax code:-

```
<script>

 $('#cat').click(function(){
 var package = $('#cat').val();
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       data:{package:package},
       url:'ajaxdropdown.php',
       success:function(data){
           $('#pnum').val(data);
      } 

      });

 });
 </script>
```

ajaxdropdown.php

```
<?php
include('session.php');
if (isset($_POST['package'])) {
    $query = "select * from `user_content` where Category=" . $_POST['package'];
// for method 1

$result1 = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
            echo $res['Mobile'];
        }   
}
die();

}
      ?>
```

Actually the problem was Dropdown fetch the category values perfectly. but the appropriate Category selection of mobile value does not display the textbox field.

Table name : user_content

Fields:-

ID    Mobile   Content      DateTime          Category

1     969696    test   2018-06-26 08:05:35    Stencil
2     959563    reel   2018-06-26 08:05:35    Tooling
3     562356    demo   2018-06-26 08:05:35   Management

Comment: When you said the problem "was" [...] Does that mean you fixed the issue, or do you still have any problems?